# How to parse complex data from Json via volley library in android studio?

Tags: java, arrays, json, android-studio, android-volley

I want to fetch data from api through volley library.

I am retrieving a JSON Object And Json Arrray via the Volley class in Android .I know how to get request but I am really struggling to parse this giant nested json .

I want to get [synonyms](https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/bad) And antonyms From the list

I want to get data from **Synonmys Array** and **antonyms** **array**....... Here is the link to api . [Link](https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/bad)

or Image Of Json Api - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYbNZ.png)

My Main Activity

```
  JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, JSON_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                // creating a new json object and
                // getting each object from our json array.
                try {
                    // we are getting each json object.
                    JSONObject responseObj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    String word = responseObj.getString("word");
                    String phonetic = responseObj.getString("phonetic");

                    JSONArray jsonArray = responseObj.getJSONArray("meaning");
                    for (int k = 0; k < response.length(); k++) {

                      ?? what to do here ????????

------------------------need help here-------------------------------


                    }

                    synonymsList.add(new synonymsModel(word,phonetic, synonyms,antonyms));
                    buildRecyclerView();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

Model class

```
public class synonymsModel {

  String word, phonetic , antonyms, synonyms;

    public synonymsModel(String word, String phonetic, String antonyms, String synonyms) {
        this.word = word;
        this.phonetic = phonetic;
        this.antonyms = antonyms;
        this.synonyms = synonyms;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public String getPhonetic() {
        return phonetic;
    }

    public void setPhonetic(String phonetic) {
        this.phonetic = phonetic;
    }

    public String getAntonyms() {
        return antonyms;
    }

    public void setAntonyms(String antonyms) {
        this.antonyms = antonyms;
    }

    public String getSynonyms() {
        return synonyms;
    }

    public void setSynonyms(String synonyms) {
        this.synonyms = synonyms;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to convert your json to your java object model.

**First** , you need a mapping lib for your case
It the best so far with [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

**Second** , you need to create a model of your need.

I personally use this for [java class](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

After all that 2 setup all you have to do convert

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String json = gson.toJson(anything); // serializes target to Json
 YourClass your class = gson.fromJson(json, YourClass.class); //
```

You don't have to call loop for i either for each , while you can map your while object itself.